# Sharepoint 2010 opening non-office documents needs Widows SharePoint Services compatible app

Tags: adobe-reader, sharepoint-2010

We have documents stored in a SharePoint 2010 site. When people trying to open non-Office documents, like PDFs and JPGs, they get a message "The document could not be opened for editing. A Windows SharePoint Services compatbile application could not be found to edit the document."

Is there a way to eliminate this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that Adobe X has added SharePoint support. You can now checkout and checkin documents from the Adobe products.